# Unable to use Stack Overflow Careers 2.0 Invitation

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, jobs, invitation

Hi all,

Today, I got a mail with an invite to create an account on Stack Overflow Careers 2.0. But, I already have an account on careers, which is a free one (no profile).

So, when I used the invitation link, it said, I can't use the mentioned email id, as it is used by some other account (I guess the old free account that I created) and suggested me to logout and re-login. I logged out and after that, when I click the invitation link to create the profile, it says it can't find that invite anymore.

Does anyone know if this is expected or any suggested resolution to get the invitation working with my old account?

PS: I requested for an invitation on Careers 2.0 after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that.  You should be able to edit your profile now.

Comment: Thank you. Now, I am able to create my profile.

Comment: @Mahesh: No problem.

Comment: Yay! Soon you will have a careeer!! How good for you \o/